# Adding Searchview in Listview android

Tags: android, listview, searchview

I want to add a searchview to filter results. Please help me with this. I have tried all the methods available online but all are for custom adapter and none seems to be working for my project.

My MainActivity.class

```
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing;

 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("contacts");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String address = c.getString("address");
                    String gender = c.getString("gender");

                    // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String office = phone.getString("office");

                    // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("email", email);
                    contact.put("mobile", mobile);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{"name", "email",
                "mobile"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```

My HttpHandler.class

```
package info.androidhive.jsonparsing;

import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;

/**
* Created by Ravi Tamada on 01/09/16.
* www.androidhive.info
*/
public class HttpHandler {

private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

public HttpHandler() {
}

public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: this [post](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/android-searchview-in-listview-example-tutorial/) may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use latest recylerview to achieve this (robust and better performance)
Or Easy way: try this [MaterialSearchViewlibrary](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)